# How to use argocd app diff with --revision flag?

Tags: argocd

What is the syntax to specify a revision for this command? The documentation doesn't include examples and all my guesses have been wrong so far.
I've tried:

`argocd app diff my-app --revision <commit sha>`

`argocd app diff my-app --revision <branch>`

`argocd app diff my-app --revision <full url to commit>`

`argocd app diff my-app --revision <full url to branch>`

For all of these options, I get `git checkout --force <revision> failed exit status 128: fatal: reference is not a tree:` even though I can absolutely successfully check out the revision parameters I've used. I've also tried adding the `--refresh` and `--hard-refresh` flags to these commands with the same result.

Comment: Maybe you have some special authentication for this repo? Did you deploy the application ok in ArgoCD?

Answer (score 0):

The revision arguments expects a commit SHA. The error that you get is probably unrelated to ArgoCD, and has to do with how you access/use your Git repository.